# Which python mpi library to use?

Tags: python, mpi

I'm starting work on some simulations using MPI and want to do the programming in Python/scipy. The scipy [site](http://www.scipy.org/Topical_Software#head-cf472934357fda4558aafdf558a977c4d59baecb) lists a number of mpi libraries, but I was hoping to get feedback on quality, ease of use, etc from anyone who has used one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have heard good things about [mpi4py](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/) (but I have never used it myself). That's what a colleague recommended who looked at all the alternatives. He mentioned the completeness as one advantage.

Answer (score 4):

Also check whether [pymw](http://pymw.sourceforge.net/) (master/worker framework) might help you. It supports various backends (MPI via pympi, Boinc, ..)

Answer (score 2):

I've used pypar on 64 bit windows server with MPICH2.  It is easy to use, requires no special structures or constants and you can send almost any python object, list or dictionary about with no effort.  The developer is also available to ask questions about.